# Matching the first line after a bracket in Lint

Tags: regex, lint

I'm making a custom rule for programming language [Lint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8503586/7975442) to :

- match 1 or more empty lines after `{`, and
- another rule to match empty line before `}`.

As an example in this code, I want these rules to match line 2 and line 5 :

```
class Test {                   /* Line 1 */
                               /* Line 2 */
  func example() {             /* Line 3 */
  }                            /* Line 4 */
                               /* Line 5 */
}
```

I had tried to do it with positive lookahead/lookbehind but with no luck `(?<=\{)\n`.

Could anyone help with it ?

**Update:**

Added whitespeace to the example.

```
class Test { 

  func example() { 
  }

}
```

Comment: @C0deDaedalus, you created the [lint] tag.  I'm waiting for questions using it like, "there's a lot of lint clogging the fan and my system is overheating".  Can you add at least a wiki excerpt with usage guidance on the tag (a wiki entry would also be good)?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, sure would do that. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is matching what you want:

```
\{\h*\R\K\h*\R|\R\K\h*\R(?=\h*\})
//added__^^^
```

**Explanation:**

```
  \{    : open brace
  \h*   : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \R    : any kind of line break
  \K    : forget all we have seen until this position
  \h*   : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \R    : any kind of line break
|       : OR
  \R    : any kind of line break
  \K    : forget all we have seen until this position
  \h*   : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \R    : any kind of line break
  (?=   : positive lookahead
    \h* : 0 or more horizontal spaces
    \}  : close brace
  )     : end lookahead
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was wanted, thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: If the empty line contains whitespace it won't detect it. Any suggestion how to do it? I provided new sample in the answer.

Comment: @FerasAlnatsheh: I missed a `\h*`, it was noted in explanation but not present in online regex. See my edit